# Writing .csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
data=open('c:/Users/Envy x360/Documents/Python Lesson1/result.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
csv_data=csv.reader(data)
data_list=list(csv_data)
#print(data_list)
dd=len(data_list)
#dd=dd-1
#print(dd)
student_result=[]#*dd
for kk in data_list[0:(dd)]:
    gg=[kk[0],kk[13]]
    student_result.append(gg)
print(student_result)
file_open=open('result_to_announce.csv', 'w', newline='') 
with file_open:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(file_open, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerows(student_result)
    file_open.close()
```

The code does exactly what it is expected to do with following output, i mean it prints student_ result, the way it is expected to do:

Output:

```
[['Student Name', 'Marks Obtained '],
 ['Hajra Masood', '218'],
 ['Anas Ikram ', '217'],
 ['Attiya Ahsan', '197'],
 ['Daniya Batool ', '221'],
 ['Haaris Chauhry', '217'],
 ['Anaum Fatima', '200'],
 ['Qaiser Ali Afandi', '209']]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Users\Envy x360\Documents\Python Lesson1\csvediting.py", line 14, in <module>
    file_open=open('result_to_announce.csv', 'w', newline='')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'result_to_announce.csv'
```

However, it gives permission denied error as shown above in the output and does not create `result_to_announce.csv`.

Comment: Have you kept open the csv in Excel? It might be because of that.

Comment: here is the link of input csv file filebin.net/j5ve5zr0zj87rbf3

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Most of this code is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ismail Hafeez no I have closed the excel file

Comment: "Permission denied" means your program does not have permission to write that file.  This has nothing to do with csv.

Comment: Replace your script with just the single line: `file_open=open('result_to_announce.csv', 'w', newline='')`, then search for an answer, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

Open console/cmd.

```
Cd {python file directory}
```

After entering into directory type

```
python filename.py --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing current directory resolved the problem.